# PostgreSQL function returning multiple result sets

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, set, plpgsql

Is it possible to return multiple result sets from a PostgreSQL function, like in MSSQL:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION test
    
AS
    
SELECT * FROM first_table
    
SELECT * FROM second_table
```

Answer (score 21):

#### Return single result set from multiple queries

A simpler way has been around **since PostgreSQL 8.3**:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION test()
  RETURNS SETOF first_table
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * FROM first_table;

   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * FROM second_table;  -- same row type as first_table!
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM test();
```

Both result sets are appended to a single set returned from the function. The row type has to match, of course.
See the [manual for `RETURN QUERY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).

#### Return multiple cursors

You *could* return multiple cursors, which is not the same thing, exactly, as you have to [`FETCH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) from each cursor in turn. And you have to do it all within the same transaction. There is a [code example in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-RETURNING). It might be useful to return large row sets from a function. In most cases, I would rather just run each `SELECT` statement in turn.

Comment: what for different row types? is there any solution? other than cursor. I am looking to get two recordsets on one call.

Comment: @UdeetSolanki: Not possible as direct result from a function. There are various ways around it: with cursors, temp tables, document types like `json`. I suggest you ask a new question, comments are not the place.

Comment: Any improvement as of Postgres11?

Comment: @MaulikModi: This cannot be "improved" as it's an inherent restriction of the SQL language. Consider asking a new question with details of your case.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Other DBMS support returning multiple, hetereogenous, resultsets from a query batch within a procedure: they return _1-distinct-resultset-per-`SELECT`-statement_ . It's not a limitation of SQL per-se, but a limitation of Postgres, no?

Comment: @Dai: Well, you are right, in principle. The SQL standard is pretty narrow on functions.

Answer (score 9):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "pr_GetCustomersAndOrders"()
RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS
$BODY$DECLARE
customerRC refcursor;
orderRC refcursor;
BEGIN
open customerRC FOR
SELECT * FROM customers;
RETURN NEXT customerRC;

open orderRC FOR
SELECT * FROM orders;
RETURN NEXT orderRC;
RETURN;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
ALTER FUNCTION "pr_GetCustomersAndOrders"() OWNER TO postgres;
```

I.o.w. using refcursors :)

Comment: Fitting this to my tables I get:
`SELECT [* FROM] "pr_GetCustomersAndOrders"();
 pr_GetCustomersAndOrders 
--------------------------
 <unnamed portal 11>
 <unnamed portal 12>`
Using psql 9.1.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.TestReturnMultipleTales
( 
 param_coid integer, 
 ref1 refcursor,
 ref2 refcursor
)
RETURNS SETOF refcursor 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
            
BEGIN
  OPEN ref1 FOR SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl1 WHERE coid = param_coid;
  RETURN NEXT ref1;

  OPEN ref2 FOR SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl2 LIMIT 5;
  RETURN NEXT ref2;
END;
$BODY$;

USE IN pgSQL Query:- 

BEGIN;
    SELECT football_players.show_cities_multiple(123456, 'Ref1', 'Ref2');
    FETCH ALL IN "Ref1";
    FETCH ALL IN "Ref2";
COMMIT;

SELECT football_players.show_cities_multiple(123456, 'Ref1', 'Ref2');
FETCH ALL IN "Ref1";

SELECT football_players.show_cities_multiple(123456, 'Ref1', 'Ref2');
FETCH ALL IN "Ref2";
```

Answer (score 0):

If `first_table` and `second_table` have the same layout, you can also just use

```
SELECT * FROM first_table WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM second_table WHERE ...
```

**[EDIT: Thanks to a commenter (whose name is probably not "null" :) ) for pointing out that `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION`.]**

Comment: Nitpicking, but UNION ALL would be quicker (there is no "| sort | uniq"), but will return duplicates if there are any.

Comment: @null: Good point; updated. (I realise your name probably isn't "null" -- seems a recent SO bug causes this. I was able to fix it by editing the top field on my profile page.)

Comment: Yes but what about queries that don't return the same layouts ? It quite limitative if we need to get many sets. I use to have Stored Procedure in SQL Server which returns 10+ result sets. Anything like that in PostgreSQL ?

Comment: @MaxiWheat: Frans Bouma's answer (returning REFCURSORs) covers that case, provided you remain within plpgsql. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html explains how cursors can be passed back outside of plpgsql (e.g. to be used with a client library).

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use multiple `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` statements in `my_func()` which returns `SETOF RECORD` type as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE 
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT row; -- Here
  END LOOP;
  FOR row IN VALUES ('Robert','Wilson'), ('Mark','Taylor') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT row; -- Here
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller'); -- Here
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('Robert','Wilson'), ('Mark','Taylor'); -- Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*Memos:

- A `RETURN NEXT` and `RETURN QUERY` statement cannot exit a function while a [RETURN statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN) can.
- You can also use a `RETURN NEXT` and `RETURN QUERY` statement together in `my_func()` as I explain it in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249390/using-return-next-and-return-query-in-the-same-postgres-function#77983325):

Then, calling `my_func()` returns 4 rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func() AS (first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT);
 first_name | last_name
------------+-----------
 John       | Smith
 David      | Miller
 Robert     | Wilson
 Mark       | Taylor
(4 rows)
```

And, you can use multiple `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` statements in `my_func()` which returns `TABLE()` type as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT) AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR first_name, last_name IN VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT; -- Here
  END LOOP;
  FOR first_name, last_name IN VALUES ('Robert','Wilson'), ('Mark','Taylor') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT; -- Here
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller'); -- Here
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('Robert','Wilson'), ('Mark','Taylor'); -- Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns 4 rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
 first_name | last_name
------------+-----------
 John       | Smith
 David      | Miller
 Robert     | Wilson
 Mark       | Taylor
(4 rows)
```

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
     my_func
-----------------
 (John,Smith)
 (David,Miller)
 (Robert,Wilson)
 (Mark,Taylor)
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

Example:

```
test=# create function x () returns setof integer language plpgsql as $$ begin return next 1; return next 2; end $$;
CREATE FUNCTION
test=# select * from x();
 x 
---
 1
 2
(2 rows)
```

You can of course use an existing table/view or a custom type for the returned type.

Example using language SQL:

```
test=# create table customer (name varchar, birth_date date);
CREATE TABLE
test=# create function y () returns setof customer language sql as $$ 
select * from customer
union all
select * from customer
$$;
CREATE FUNCTION
test=# insert into customer values ('joe', now()::date);
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into customer values ('jill', now()::date);
INSERT 0 1
test=# select * from y();
 name | birth_date 
------+------------
 joe  | 2009-04-16
 jill | 2009-04-16
 joe  | 2009-04-16
 jill | 2009-04-16
(4 rows)
```

[See here for doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html)

Comment: You only use 1 table, the table "customer". The question is about multiple result sets!