# Access \set variables in psql for Postgres function bodies

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql, stored-functions, citus

I am creating a generic automated Postgres script which includes DDL, DML, functions and triggers. I have achieved to parameterize the schema name with `\set` in psql in most of the operation but it's not working in case of **function bodies**. I've searched hard and found about the **dynamic SQL** but that also doesn't seem to work.

**script.sql**

```
\set schema_name myschema

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS :schema_name;

CREATE table :schema_name.employee (
 id serial,
 name text ,
 dob timestamp,
 leaves_count int,
 CONSTRAINT employee_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

SELECT create_distributed_table(concat(:'schema_name', '.employee'), 'id');


CREATE table :schema_name.leaves (
 id serial,
 reason text,
 ts timestamp,
 employee_id int,
 CONSTRAINT leaves_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- STORED PROCEDURE
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION :schema_name.deduct_leave_count() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$ BEGIN
UPDATE
    :schema_name.employee s
SET
    leaves_count = s.leaves_count - 1
WHERE
    s.id = NEW.employee_id;
RETURN NEW;
END $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- TRIGGER
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_deduct_leave_count BEFORE
INSERT
    ON
    :schema_name.leaves FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE :schema_name.deduct_leave_count();
```

> psql -p 5432 -f script.sql

I am getting error in function as it can't read the variable set globally. Is there any way to access the global variable or -v flag of psql inside functions?

**Execution Logs:**

[image: Execution Logs]

Comment: That doesn't work because the function body is a string constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of a function is a quoted literal. Dollar-quoted, but all the same. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION)

> Variable interpolation will not be performed within quoted SQL
>   literals and identifiers.

There are various ways around this. Since you are running a script in psql, I suggest you let Postgres do the concatenation for you with [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) and execute with `\gexec`:

```
-- TRIGGER FUNCTION
SELECT format($$
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %1$I.deduct_leave_count()
  RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE %1$I.employee s
   SET    leaves_count = s.leaves_count - 1
   WHERE  s.id = NEW.employee_id;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$
$$, :'schema_name')\gexec
```

Detailed explanation:

- [How to pass variable to PL/pgSQL code from the command line?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/240542/3684)

Aside 1: A (trigger) function is *not* a procedure. Related:

- [How to get result set from PostgreSQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507979/how-to-get-result-set-from-postgresql-stored-procedure/58513796#58513796)

Aside 2: Since a schema name is an identifier, you may want to use double-quotes. psql supports that:

```
CREATE table :"schema_name".leaves
```

Preserves the string as given (incl. capitalization) and defends against SQL injection.

`format()` with  `%I` is a bit smarter and only adds double quotes where they make a difference. This avoids noise in the function definition. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)