# How to return a value from a stored procedure (not function)?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, plpgsql

I have a Stored Procedure that inserts, updates or deletes tablerows. It was working fine while all parameters were used as input. However, I need to return the ID of last inserted row. For that I tried using an `INOUT` parameter and `RETURNING` after the `INSERT` statement to return the ID.

However, I am not sure how to bind the returned ID to the `INOUT` parameter. Following is the code for stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.spproductinsertupdatedelete(
_ser integer,
_subcategid integer,
_inrprice numeric,
_usdprice numeric,
_colour integer,
_size integer,
_qty integer,
_prodid integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
inout _pid integer default null
 )
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
  if _ser=1 then --- Insert
    INSERT INTO product (prod_subcateg_id,prod_inr_price,prod_usd_price,prod_colour,prod_size,prod_qty)
    VALUES (_subcategID, _inrprice, _usdprice, _colour, _size, _qty)
    RETURNING prod_id;

ELSEIF _ser=2 THEN
    
    UPDATE PRODUCT SET
    prod_subcateg_id = _subcategid,
    prod_inr_price = _inrprice,
    prod_usd_price = _usdprice,
    prod_size = _size,
    prod_colour = _colour,
    prod_qty=_qty
    where prod_id = _prodID;

ELSEIF _ser=3 THEN ---- Delete
    UPDATE PRODUCT SET prod_datetill = now()
    WHERE prod_id = _prodID;
    
end if;

END
$BODY$;
```

On executing above stored procedure, I receive this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
> ```

Comment: You might want to use `_pid = INSERT …`?

Comment: You can't use OUT, you have to use INOUT:[SP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createprocedure.html) "The mode of an argument: IN, INOUT, or VARIADIC. If omitted, the default is IN. (OUT arguments are currently not supported for procedures. Use INOUT instead.)"

Comment: If you want to return something, use a function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Proof of concept

A [`PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) *can* return values, but in a very limited fashion (as of Postgres 13).

[The manual on `CALL`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html)

> `CALL` executes a procedure.
>
> If the procedure has any output parameters, then a result row will be
> returned, containing the values of those parameters.

[The manual on `CREATE PROCEDURE`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html#id-1.9.3.76.6)

> ***`argmode`***
>
> The mode of an argument: `IN`, `INOUT`, or `VARIADIC`. If omitted, the default is `IN`. (`OUT` arguments are currently not supported for procedures. Use `INOUT` instead.)

So your use of the `INOUT` mode is correct. But the assignment in the function body is missing. And some other things are wrong / suboptimal. I suggest:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.spproductinsertupdatedelete(
  _ser        int
, _subcategid int
, _inrprice   numeric
, _usdprice   numeric
, _colour     int
, _size       int
, _qty        int
, INOUT _prod_id int DEFAULT NULL
)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
BEGIN
   CASE _ser    -- simpler than IF
   WHEN 1 THEN  -- INSERT
      INSERT INTO product
             (prod_subcateg_id, prod_inr_price, prod_usd_price, prod_colour, prod_size, prod_qty)
      VALUES (_subcategid     , _inrprice     , _usdprice     , _colour    , _size    , _qty    )
      RETURNING prod_id
      INTO _prod_id;   -- !!!

   WHEN 2 THEN  -- UPDATE
      UPDATE product
      SET   (prod_subcateg_id, prod_inr_price, prod_usd_price, prod_size, prod_colour, prod_qty)
          = (_subcategid     , _inrprice     , _usdprice     , _size    , _colour    , _qty)
      WHERE  prod_id = _prod_id;

   WHEN 3 THEN  -- soft-DELETE
      UPDATE product
      SET    prod_datetill = now()
      WHERE  prod_id = _prod_id;

   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpected _ser value: %', _ser;
   END CASE;
END
$proc$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f08dcd1167c3b2149b262f5cdca9278e)*

Take this as proof of concept. But I see nothing in the question warranting the use of a [`PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) in the first place.

#### You probably want a [`FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)

A `FUNCTION` offers more options to return values, doesn't need to be run separately with `CALL`, and can be integrated in bigger queries. Chances are, that's what you wanted in the first place, and you were just being mislead by the widespread misnomer "stored procedure". See:

- [How to get result set from PostgreSQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507979/how-to-get-result-set-from-postgresql-stored-procedure/58513796#58513796)

Moreover, in the current form, you have to provide many noise parameters if you want to update or soft-delete a row. Plain SQL commands might do the job. Or separate functions ...

The **rule of thumb**: if you don't need to manage transactions from within, you probably want to use a function instead of a procedure. Later, Postgres procedures may be extended to be able and return multiple result sets (per SQL standard), but not yet (pg 13).

See:

- [In PostgreSQL, what is the difference between a “Stored Procedure” and other types of functions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194811/3684)
- [Do stored procedures run in database transaction in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250376/do-stored-procedures-run-in-database-transaction-in-postgres/28251922#28251922)
- https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-11-server-side-procedures-part-1/#comment-72
- [What are the differences between “Stored Procedures” and “Stored Functions”?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/262662/3684)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked. I am using 'Functions' wherever I have to return a result set and for rest of CRUD functions, I am using procedures. Is this approach not okay?
The reason why I have not made different Update and soft-delete function is due to large numbers of tables. I thought to have one 'Procedure' to do Insert/ Update/ Delete for each table in order to have better management. Please suggest if I can improve in this.

Comment: @Kartikeya: I added a rule of thumb and some more links to details. And I would probably split the function / procedure into three separate ones for INSERT / UPDATE / soft-DELETE - or simply use SQL commands directly.

Answer (score 0):

I used inout arguments in my procedure and then select suppose count into that inout variable i could have my multiple outputs returned from the procedure.