# How to force COMMIT inside function so other sessions can see updated row?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions, plpgsql, task-queue

In a Postgres 12 database, I have multiple queries (`SELECT`, `UPDATE`, ...) in a function that all together take about 20 minutes to complete.
I have a check at the top that does an `UPDATE` if `status` is not running:

```
create or replace function aaa.fnc_work() returns varchar as 
$body$
    begin
        if (select count(*) from aaa.monitor where id='invoicing' and status='running')=0 then
           return 'running';
        else
           update aaa.monitor set status='running' where id='invoicing';
        end if;
        --- rest of code ---
        --finally
        update aaa.monitor set status='idle' where id='invoicing';
        return '';
    exception when others then
         return SQLERRM::varchar;
    end
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

The idea is to prevent other users from executing the `--- rest of code ---` until `status` is idle.

However, it seems the updated status is not seen by others (calling the same function) who also go ahead and start executing `--- rest of code ---`. How do I force a commit after:

> update aaa.monitor set status='running' `where id='invoicing'`;

So that all other user sessions can see the updated `status` and exit accordingly.

Do I need a transaction?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Keep reading. I preserved the best for last.

#### Proof of concept with a `PROCEDURE`

A Postgres [`FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) is always atomic (runs inside a single transaction wrapper) and cannot handle transactions. So `COMMIT` is disallowed. You *could* use tricks with `dblink` to work around this. See:

- [Does Postgres support nested or autonomous transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425944/does-postgres-support-nested-or-autonomous-transactions/25428060#25428060)
- [How do I do large non-blocking updates in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113277/how-do-i-do-large-non-blocking-updates-in-postgresql/22163648#22163648)

But for nested transactions like this consider a **[`PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)** instead. Introduced with **Postgres 11**. There you can manage transactions:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE aaa.proc_work(_id text, INOUT _result text = NULL)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
BEGIN
   -- optionally assert steering row exists
   PERFORM FROM aaa.monitor WHERE id = _id FOR KEY SHARE SKIP LOCKED;

   IF NOT FOUND THEN   
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'monitor.id = % not found or blocked!', quote_literal(_id);
   END IF;

   -- try UPDATE
   UPDATE aaa.monitor
   SET    status = 'running'
   WHERE  id = _id                   -- assuming valid _id
   AND    status <> 'running';       -- assuming "status" is NOT NULL

   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      _result := 'running'; RETURN;  -- this is how you return with INOUT params
   END IF;

   COMMIT;                           -- HERE !!!

   BEGIN                             -- start new code block

      ----- code for big work HERE -----
      -- PERFORM 1/0;                -- debug: test exception?
      -- PERFORM pg_sleep(5);        -- debug: test concurrency?

      _result := '';

   -- also catching QUERY_CANCELED and ASSERT_FAILURE
   -- is a radical step to try and release 'running' rows no matter what
   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS OR QUERY_CANCELED OR ASSERT_FAILURE THEN
      -- ROLLBACK;                   -- roll back (unfinished?) big work
      _result := SQLERRM;
   END;                              -- end of nested block

   UPDATE aaa.monitor                -- final reset
   SET    status = 'idle'
   WHERE  id = _id
   AND    status <> 'idle';          -- only if needed
END
$proc$;
```

Call (important!):

```
CALL aaa.proc_work('invoicing');  -- stand-alone call!
```

#### Important notes

Add `COMMIT` after the `UPDATE`. After that, concurrent transactions can see the updated row.

But there is no additional `BEGIN` or `START TRANSACTION`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html)

> In procedures invoked by the `CALL` command as well as in anonymous code
> blocks (`DO` command), it is possible to end transactions using the
> commands `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK`. A new transaction is started
> automatically after a transaction is ended using these commands, so
> there is no separate `START TRANSACTION` command. (Note that `BEGIN` and
> `END` have different meanings in PL/pgSQL.)

We need a separate PL/pgSQL [**code block**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html), because you have a custom exception handler, and (quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html)):

> A transaction cannot be ended inside a block with exception handlers.

(But we can `COMMIT` / `ROLLBACK` in the `EXCEPTION` handler.)

You cannot call this procedure inside an outer transaction, or together with any other DML statement, which would force an outer transaction wrapper. Has to be a stand-alone `CALL`. See:

- [Unable to Create COMMIT inside PostgreSQL 11.5 Procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/249453/3684)

Note the final `UPDATE aaa.monitor SET status = 'idle' WHERE ...`. Else the (committed!) `status` would remain 'running' indefinitely after an exception.

About returning a value from a procedure:

- [How to return a value from a stored procedure (not function)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981538/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-stored-procedure-not-function/62982870#62982870)

I added `DEFAULT NULL` to the `INOUT` parameter, so you don't have to provide an argument with the call.

`UPDATE` directly. If the row is 'running', no update occurs. (This also fixes the logic: your `IF` expression seems backwards as it returns 'running' when *no* row with `status='running'` is found. Seems like you'd want the opposite.)

I added an (optional!) assert to make sure the row in table `aaa.monitor` exists. Adding a `FOR KEY SHARE` lock to also eliminate the tiny time window for a race conditions between the assert and the following `UPDATE`. The lock conflicts with deletion or updating the PK column - but *not* with updating the `status`. So the exception is never raised in normal operation! [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS)

> Currently, the set of columns considered for the `UPDATE` case are
> those that have a unique index on them that can be used in a foreign
> key (so partial indexes and expressional indexes are not considered),
> but this may change in the future.

`SKIP LOCK` to not wait in case of a conflicting lock. The added exception should never occur. Just demonstrating a water-tight proof of concept.

Your update revealed 25 rows in `aaa.monitor`, so I added the parameter `_id`.

### Superior approach

The above might make sense to persist more information for the world to see. To just queue operations, there are **much more efficient** solutions. Work with a **lock** instead, which is "visible" to others instantaneously. Then you don't need a nested transaction to begin with, and a plain `FUNCTION` will do:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aaa.fnc_work(_id text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   -- optionally assert that the steering row exists
   PERFORM FROM aaa.monitor WHERE id = _id FOR KEY SHARE SKIP LOCKED;
   IF NOT FOUND THEN   
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'monitor.id = % not found or blocked!', quote_literal(_id);
   END IF;

   -- lock row
   PERFORM FROM aaa.monitor WHERE id = _id FOR NO KEY UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;

   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      -- we made sure the row exists, so it must be locked
      RETURN 'running';
   END IF;

   ----- code for big work HERE -----
   -- PERFORM 1/0;                -- debug: test exception?
   -- PERFORM pg_sleep(5);        -- debug: test concurrency?

   RETURN '';

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   RETURN SQLERRM;

END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT aaa.fnc_work('invoicing');
```

The call can be nested any way you want. As long as one transaction is working on the big job, no other will start.

Again, the optional assert takes out a `FOR KEY SHARE` lock to eliminate the time window for a race condition, and the added exception should never occur in normal operation.

We don't need the column `status` at all for this. The row-lock itself is the gatekeeper. Hence the empty `SELECT` list in `PERFORM FROM aaa.monitor ...`. Collateral benefit: this also doesn't produce dead tuples by updating the row back and forth. If you still need to update `status` for some other reason, you are back to the visibility issue of the previous chapter. You can combine both ...

About `PERFORM`:

- [SELECT or PERFORM in a PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115806/select-or-perform-in-a-pl-pgsql-function/10117015#10117015)

About the row lock:

- [Postgres UPDATE … LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)

Comment: Thank you so so so much for your awesome answer. I have taken note of all the options I have. I want to go with the **Superior approach**. In my initial post I missed out `where id='invoicing'` as aa.monitor has multiple rows. Can I ask, with multiple rows, can I still use lock as I will be updating the same record ? and where is the update of `status` to 'running' is this case ? I don't see it it the lock approach solution

Comment: @KofiB: I adapted to multiple IDs. The "superior approach" works all the same. There is no actual `UPDATE`, just a row lock. That's the beauty of it - for efficiency and visibility.

Comment: @KofiB: I updated for two fine points: 1. Eliminate corner-case for race condition in procedure and function. 2. `UPDATE` directly in the procedure, that's faster.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to accomplish is an Autonomous Transaction. PostgreSQL doesn't have an easy way to do this. This link [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/implementing-autonomous-transactions-in-postgres/) discusses some alternatives.

But one way, which is discussed in the article linked aboove is to use the PostgreSQL dblink extension.

You will need to add the extension to the server

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

and then you can create a new function that is called from within your function

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_monitor_via_dblink(msg text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
   select dblink('host=/var/run/postgresql port=5432 user=postgres dbname=postgres',
    format(' update aaa.monitor set status= %M',msg::text)
$function$;
```

Another thing you might want to consider is using PostgreSQL locks. More information can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/explicit-locking.html).

Comment: Thanks you @Ed Mendez. Solution very well noted