# Do I need a trigger, a function, or a procedure?

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

This should technically “trigger” and continuously update the summary table as things are added into the detailed table. I think I am missing something in the code?

This should be a stored procedure. Do I just need to change it from `FUNCTION` to `PROCEDURE`? It seems to work correctly, but I think right now I have it as a function?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_restaurant()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO summary_table (titles_of_recipes, total_recipes, location_restaurant)

VALUES (NEW.titles_of_recipes, NEW.total_recipes, NEW.location_restaurant);
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER summary_insert_trigger
AFTER UPDATE
ON detailed_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_restaurant();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_data()
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN

DELETE FROM detailed_table;
DELETE FROM summary_table;

INSERT INTO detailed_table (total_recipes, inventory_id, location_restaurant, titles_of_recipes)
SELECT
    COUNT(recipe.recipe_id) AS total_recipes,
    inventory.inventory_id AS inventory_id,
    location_restaurant(restaurant.restaurant_id) AS location_restaurant,
    film.title AS titles_of_recipes
FROM 
   recipes
JOIN 
    inventory ON recipe.recipe_id = inventory.recipe_id
JOIN 
    store ON inventory.store_id = store.store_id
GROUP BY
    inventory.inventory_id, location_restaurant(restaurant.restaurant_id), film.title
ORDER BY
    total_of_recipes DESC;

INSERT INTO summary_table (titles_of_recipes, total_of_recipes, location_restaurant)
SELECT
    titles_of_recipes,
    SUM(total_of_recipes) AS total_of_recipes,
    location_restaurant
FROM detailed_table
GROUP BY
    titles_of_recipes, location_restaurant;

RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT refresh_data();
```

Comment: Don't use Google when you have the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html And Yes, a function is fine.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

#### Terminology

The term "stored procedure" is just misleading. A misnomer as far as Postgres is concerned. Typically, you want a function in Postgres, when that term is uttered. But it's just ambiguous. See:

- [Struggling to create a "stored procedure" beyond INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71897542/struggling-to-create-a-stored-procedure-beyond-insert/71898180#71898180)

A trigger in Postgres executes a **function**. The syntax for `CREATE TRIGGER` still allows the misleading keyword `PROCEDURE`, but since Postgres 11, the more appropriate term `FUNCTION` should be used (unless you need to stay compatible with outdated Postgres versions). See:

- [Trigger uses a procedure or a function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/307500/3684)
- [When to use stored procedure / user-defined function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118419/3684)

#### Your code

The job of "updating the summary table" is split in your code. The function `refresh_data()` adds an actual summary, the trigger copies individual rows.

Looks syntactically OK (mostly), but needlessly complicated and expensive. Drop the trigger. Do it all in the function. One big multi-row `INSERT` is much cheaper than triggering a single row `INSERT` for ever row. Plus, you can do it all in a single command with a CTE. Even cheaper yet.

And since you are not returning anything, nor does it seem to be nested anywhere, it might actually just be a `PROCEDURE` after all. (But that's optional.)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE refresh_data()
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM detailed_table;  -- TRUNCATE? See below!
   DELETE FROM summary_table;

   WITH ins1 AS (
      INSERT INTO detailed_table (inventory_id, location_restaurant, titles_of_recipes, total_recipes)
      SELECT i.inventory_id AS inventory_id
           , location_restaurant(restaurant.restaurant_id) AS location_restaurant  -- see below!
           , film.title AS titles_of_recipes
           , count(*) AS total_recipes
      FROM   recipes   r
      JOIN   inventory i USING (recipe_id)
      JOIN   store     s USING (store_id)
      GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3
      ORDER  BY total_of_recipes DESC
      RETURNING *
      )
   INSERT INTO summary_table
         (  titles_of_recipes,   total_recipes,   location_restaurant)
   SELECT i.titles_of_recipes, i.total_recipes, i.location_restaurant
   FROM   ins1 i
   UNION ALL
   SELECT titles_of_recipes
        , SUM(total_of_recipes) AS total_of_recipes  -- may need a cast! like: SUM(total_of_recipes)::int
        , location_restaurant
   FROM   ins1
   GROUP  BY titles_of_recipes, location_restaurant;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
CALL refresh_data();
```

See:

- [PL/pgSQL: PERFORM vs CALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67709708/pl-pgsql-perform-vs-call/67711519#67711519)

Only `location_restaurant(restaurant.restaurant_id)` does not make sense. There is no table `restaurant` in the query. Fix that bit.

If your table(s) are big, consider `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE`. See:

- [PostgreSQL delete all content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223820/postgresql-delete-all-content/13226257#13226257)

`SUM(<bigint column>)` returns type `numeric`. Your code may need an explicit cast. Like:

```
SUM(total_of_recipes)::bigint AS total_of_recipes
```