# How to call postgres function with an out parameter

Tags: postgresql

I have a basic function that accepts 3 arguments. 2 in parameters and 1 out parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE document_copy(IN p_name character varying, IN p_id smallint, INOUT p_new_id smallint)
```

I've tried a couple ways of executing this function but I get this error whichever methods I've tried function document_copy(character varying, smallint) does not exist

I've tried

```
select  (document_template_copy_one ('Test'::varchar, 1::smallint)).*
```

---

```
DO $$
DECLARE  
 test SMALLINT;
BEGIN  
    select  dust.document_template_copy_one ('Mexico Passport'::varchar, 1::smallint,  test) into test ;
END $$;
```

---

```
DO $$
DECLARE  
 test SMALLINT;
BEGIN  
    select  dust.document_template_copy_one ('Mexico Passport'::varchar, 1::smallint) into test ;
END $$;
```

any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: a procedure is no function and must be called with `CALL(dust.document_template_copy_one ('Mexico Passport'::varchar, 1::smallint,  test) )`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a value from a stored procedure (not function)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981538/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-stored-procedure-not-function)