# I'm trying to create a SQL procedure. ERROR: syntax error (example position: "SELECT")

Tags: sql, postgresql, eclipse

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    SELECT  'hello, I am a Procedure' AS hi;
END
```

Error:

```
ERROR: syntax error (example position: "SELECT")
LINE 3: SELECT 'hello, I am a Procedure' AS hi;
          ^

ERROR: syntax error (example position: "SELECT")
SQL state: 42601
Character: 32
```

I'm trying to create a procedure but nothing works and I don't know what to do, I've surfed the Internet. I use sql Scrapbook (eclipse (java)), I tried to run the query through pgAdmin 4, it didn’t work either.

Comment: See the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html#SQL-CREATEPROCEDURE-EXAMPLES

Comment: Are you sure you want a `PROCEDURE` and not a (more commonly used) `FUNCTION`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62982870/939860, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194811/3684, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118419/3684

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres, the [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) documentation says you can either use the `AS $$ ... $$` or the `BEGIN ATOMIC ... END` syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    SELECT  'hello, I am a Procedure' AS hi;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    SELECT  'hello, I am a Procedure' AS hi;
END;
```

For SQL Server, a [procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-en/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) without parameters is declared without parentheses, and don't forget `AS`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test1
AS BEGIN
    SELECT  'hello, I am a Procedure' AS hi;
END;
```

Comment: The Postgres examples don't make a whole lot of sense, since a procedure cannot return anything this way.

Answer (score 1):

You attempt to return a string. A [`PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) can (as of Postgres 16) only return a single row by way of using `INOUT` or `OUT` parameters. So your attempt translates to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test(INOUT hi text = NULL)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$proc$
SELECT 'hello, I am a Procedure';
$proc$;
```

Or the "SQL standard" variant in  Postgres 14 or later:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test(INOUT hi text = NULL)
  LANGUAGE sql
BEGIN ATOMIC
   SELECT 'hello, I am a Procedure';
END;
```

Or the short form for this simple case:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test(INOUT hi text = NULL)
  LANGUAGE sql
RETURN 'hello, I am a Procedure';
```

And you have to [`CALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html) a procedure to execute:

```
CALL test();
```

We can omit the `INOUT` parameter in the call because we declared `NULL` as default value (as we should).

See:

- [How to return a value from a stored procedure (not function)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981538/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-stored-procedure-not-function/62982870#62982870)
- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

I suspect you just fell for the widespread misnomer "stored procedure" and really want a [**`FUNCTION`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html).

- [When to use stored procedure / user-defined function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118419/3684)