# Stored Procedures, NPGSQL, and returning a recordset

Tags: .net, postgresql, stored-procedures, npgsql, recordset

Version 7.0 of the Npgsql dotnet client interface to PostgreSQL databases introduced a breaking change in which CommandType.StoredProcedure now calls a PostgreSQL PROCEDURE rather than a FUNCTION.

Our application uses generic code that works with several database vendors.  Generic code uses objects like DbCommand and DbConnection and DbProviderFactories.  Every database call in our vendor independent app is a call to a stored procedure.  About 1/2 the stored procedures return results as a record set from a SELECT statement.

I know that the Npgsql client can be forced back to legacy behaviour where it calls a PostgreSQL FUNCTION instead of a PROCEDURE. See: [Stored functions and procedures](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#stored-functions-and-procedures)

But, from a go forward perspective, is there a way (what is the plan) for having a PostgreSQL PROCEDURE return a record set - consistent with other database vendors?

Is there some syntax variation on OUT parameters that can return a record set in a PROCEDURE?

Here is a sample PROCEDURE that DOES NOT return any data through Npgsql...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public."AttributeSelect"()
LANGUAGE 'sql'
AS $$
   SELECT "Id" FROM "Attribute";
$$;
```

Comment: Note that there's no real need to use CommandType.StoredProcedure. You can easily invoke a stored procedure via CALL, and a stored function via SELECT * FROM. The same is typically the case in other databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, there is currently (Postgres 16) no way to return a **set** from a [`PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html). You can return a single row with `OUT` or `INOUT` parameters. See:

- [How to return a value from a stored procedure (not function)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981538/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-stored-procedure-not-function/62982870#62982870)

To return a set, use a [`FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html). A so-called "set-returning function", a.k.a. "table-function". Related:

- [How to get result set from PostgreSQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507979/how-to-get-result-set-from-postgresql-stored-procedure/58513796#58513796)