# To DIsplay one or more tables in single function in Postgresql

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

How to display one or more tables in a single function in postgres as we do in sql server stored procedure?

Sql Server

Stored Procedure: UspGetValues

```
select StudentID,studentName from students:
Select TeacherID,TeacherName from Teacher
```

Postgres Sql:
     How we need to do?

Comment: What do you mean by display one or more tables? Do you need to join these tables? Or maybe a UNION? You need to provide some more details before anybody understand the question.

Comment: You are asking if there is a way to return multiple result sets from a function in PostgreSQL as you would do from a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Comment: @Nicarus Yes you are right

Comment: You can do that if the tables have the same columns, though I don't suspect yours do. Worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756689/postgresql-function-returning-multiple-result-sets