# Pass array of tags to a plpgsql function and use it in WHERE condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I'd like to create a function that returns `items` based on their `tags`. However, I do not know how to format an array in the `IN()` clause. I believe that is why I get no result.

Here is what I got:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getItemsByTag(tags text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (id bigint, title text, tag text[]) AS $$
BEGIN
    IF array_length(tags, 1) > 0

    THEN
            EXECUTE format('
            SELECT d.id, d.title, array_agg(t.title)
            FROM items d
            INNER JOIN item_tags dt
            ON dt.item_id = d.id
            INNER JOIN tags t
            ON t.id = dt.tag_id
            AND t.title IN (%L)
            GROUP BY d.id, d.title
            ', array_to_string(tags, ','));
    -- ELSE ...
    END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then when I call:

```
select getItemsByTag('{"gaming", "sport"}');
```

I get no result even though there are items tagged with "gaming".

#### Test case

```
CREATE TABLE items(
id serial primary key,
title text);

CREATE TABLE tags(
id serial primary key,
title text);

CREATE TABLE item_tags(
item_id int references items(id),
tag_id int references tags(id),
primary key(item_id, tag_id));

insert into items (title) values ('my title 1'), ('my title 2');
insert into tags (title) values ('tag1'), ('tag2');
insert into item_tags (item_id, tag_id) values (1,1), (1, 2);
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getItemsByTag(tags text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (id bigint, title text, tag text[]) AS $$
BEGIN

    IF array_length(tags, 1) > 0

    THEN
            EXECUTE format('
            SELECT d.id, d.title, array_agg(t.title)
            FROM items d
            INNER JOIN item_tags dt
            ON dt.item_id = d.id
            INNER JOIN tags t
            ON t.id = dt.tag_id
            AND t.title IN (%L)
            GROUP BY d.id, d.title
            ', array_to_string(tags, ','));
    -- ELSE ...
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
 select getItemsByTag('{"tag1", "tag2"}');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually ***returning*** the result. You would use `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` for that. Example:

- [PostgreSQL parameterized Order By / Limit in table function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139618/postgresql-parameterized-order-by-limit-in-table-function/8146245#8146245)

But you don't need dynamic SQL here to begin with ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_items_by_tag(VARIADIC tags text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (id int, title text, tag text[]) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF array_length(tags, 1) > 0 THEN
      -- NO need for EXECUTE
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT d.id, d.title, array_agg(t.title)
      FROM   items d
      JOIN   item_tags dt ON dt.item_id = d.id
      JOIN   tags t       ON t.id = dt.tag_id
      AND    t.title = ANY ($1)     -- use ANY construct
      GROUP  BY d.id;               -- PK covers whole table
      -- array_to_string(tags, ',') -- no need to convert array with ANY
-- ELSE ...
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call with actual array:

```
SELECT * FROM get_items_by_tag(VARIADIC '{tag1,tag2}'::text[]);
```

Or call with list of items ("dictionary"):

```
SELECT * FROM get_items_by_tag('tag1', 'tag2');
```

#### Major points

- Use `RETURN QUERY` to actually return resulting rows.

  - [PostgreSQL function returning multiple result sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756689/postgresql-function-returning-multiple-result-sets/7748232#7748232)
- Don't use dynamic SQL unless you need it. (No `EXECUTE` here.)
- Use an `ANY` construct instead of `IN`. Why?

  - [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)
- I suggest a `VARIADIC` function for convenience. This way you can either pass an array or a list of items at your choosing. See:

  - [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560)
- Avoid mixed-case identifiers in Postgres if possible.

  - [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Not sure why you have `IF array_length(tags, 1) > 0 THEN`, but can probably be replaced with `IF tags IS NOT NULL THEN` or no `IF` at all and follow up with `IF NOT FOUND THEN`. More:

- [Dynamic SQL (EXECUTE) as condition for IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449011/dynamic-sql-execute-as-condition-for-if-statement/8449341#8449341)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in place of `tags` in `format` statement this:
 `'''' || array_to_string(tags, "','") || ''''`
 the result  in the IN clause will be like 
`IN ('gaming','sport')`.

Comment: Nah, there is still those `{` surrounding it. Try this `select '''' || array_to_string(ARRAY['{"tag1", "tag2"}'], ',') || '''';`

Comment: The correct Statement is: `select '''' || array_to_string(ARRAY['tag1', 'tag2'], ''',''') || '''';` - previous version has doublequoted - my mistake.
Each element in the Array statement must be a single string in a Single Quote. The result String with two elements for the IN Clause: `'tag1','tag2'` and the Delimiter must be also double quoted `''','''`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because I'm not returning anything.

```
        return query EXECUTE format('
        SELECT d.id, d.title, array_agg(t.title)
        FROM items d
        INNER JOIN item_tags dt
        ON dt.item_id = d.id
        INNER JOIN tags t
        ON t.id = dt.tag_id
        AND t.title = ANY(%L)
        GROUP BY d.id, d.title
        ', tags) ;
```